# Delete records when a size limit is reached

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3.7, I would like to ensure that when a table reaches a quantity of stored data (for example, 2 GB), the oldest 500 MB stored can be removed automatically from it. Another option that it could be useful to me is that when 2GB were reached, save it in a script (or similar) and drop the table automatically. How can I achieve this two options (or at least one of them)?

Thanks!

Comment: How can you identify 'oldest' 500MB? Do you have any column that contains the rowversion of each record?

Comment: In mysql you can query the size of a table

Comment: I identify oldest data with a timestamp or the id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your tables a column `ID` exists and row with `ID=1` is older than `ID=2` etc. I would follow these steps:

1. Check if the table has exceeded size limit.
2. If so, compute the average row size `N` in order to compute how many records need to be deleted so that we free up 500MB of storage.
3. Delete the oldest `N` rows (i.e. order the table by `ID` in ascending order).

The following stored procedure should do the trick:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `checkSizeAndDeleteRows`(IN tableName VARCHAR(30), IN schemaName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    -- Get the size of the table
    SELECT  @countMB := round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
    FROM information_schema.TABLES 
    WHERE table_schema = schemaName
        AND table_name = tableName;

    IF @countMB > 2000 THEN
        -- Compute the average row size.
        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT @avgRowSize := @countMB / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', schemaName, '.', tableName, ') INTO @avgRowSize');
        PREPARE averageSizeStmt FROM @S;
        EXECUTE averageSizeStmt; 
        SELECT @avgRowSize;

        -- Compute how many records need to be deleted in order to free up space of 500MB
        SELECT @noOfRecordsToBeDeleted := CEILING(500 / @avgRowSize);

        -- Delete the records
        SET @del = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', schemaName, '.', tableName, ' ORDER BY ID LIMIT ?');
        PREPARE deleteStmt FROM @del;
        EXECUTE deleteStmt USING @noOfRecordsToBeDeleted;
     END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can call it by executing

```
CALL checkSizeAndDelete('your_table', 'your_schema');
```

You can add a job to the scheduler and execute it for any interval and every table you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. The problem is that when I execute the 'call' I received the following sentece: 'ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected". But of course I select the database and the table that are already created.

Comment: Did you try to add USE `db_name` in the stored procedure?

Comment: @CGD You could also use `CALL db_name.checkSizeAndDeleteRows('table_name', 'schema_name');`

Comment: Ok, perfect, thanks again!. I used that command an it works perfectly. I am newbie in MySQL and I wonder how I can configure this procedure of being executing without any interruptions since the moment the database is created (and applied it to all the tables that exist in the database.) and everytime that a table surpase the limit size the procedure deletes "X" MB.

Comment: Or the procedure is already running since the moment the command is executed and it is not necessary to run it again? This is my doubt. Another thing is how I couid save/export that data before delete the MB (by using command line or procedure) with a name based for example in the timestamp and the table's name.